# проблема в том что мне надо что бы выводилось detailed status когда я хочу узнать погоду а выводит все подряд что делать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyowm

```
import pyowm
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config


config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'

owm = OWM('705458da97e384a358b99f840e0d48e8', config_dict)


place: str = input("В каком городе?:")

mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)

w = observation.weather

temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]

print("В городе " + place + " сейчас " + str(w))
print("Температура сейчас в районе " + str(temp))
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код, вставьте описание задачи в тело вопроса, приведите индексируемый заголовок. Используйте кнопку править

Answer (score 0):

Вы же выводите всю информацию `w = observation.weather`, берите только `detailed_status`

```
 print("В городе " + place + " сейчас " + w.detailed_status)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое